# Sorting arrays different ways in Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have a map(String, LinkedList) mp. This corresponds to a table like this:

```
Name   Date      Dept
Tony   4/1/2014  55125
Bob    3/2/2013  54112
Jill   7/2/2014  55265
```

(I just made these up for this example.  The first row (Name, Date, Dept) are the headings and correspond to the key value in the map (so you do an mp.get("Name") for example).  The linked list that is returned for Name is , for Date is <4/1/2014, 3/2/2013, 7/2/2014> and Dept is <55125, 54112, 55265> etc.

I need to get the list for a value and then sort it.  For Name and Dept I believe I can just do a Collections.sort(), but this will not work for date.  If date was yyyymmdd it would work, but date is mm/dd/yyyy which is not guaranteed to sort correctly, and usually won't.  I suppose I could process each entry and change it to yyyymmdd, but some of the fields will be blank (or maybe null but I think blank).

I can easily determine when to sort normally and when by date. Just not sure how to use Collections.sort() or something else to sort the date list.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Look for a Comparator example?

Comment: Hey I tried to edit and it said Dave Newton did.  Anyway, yeah I need something like that.

Comment: Maybe search the web or SO? There's plenty of information out there.

Comment: @user3257891 then what are you waiting for? Start working on a `Comparator<Object>` and use `instanceof` to check the type of the element, then move all to a single format (probably `String` or `int`) and do the comparison.

Comment: i don't see why the date won't work. convert the strings into dates then Collections.sort() on a list of java.util.Date will work

Comment: I understand.  I just get confused.  You define a class with an array of dates, and this class implements comparator.  Or do you define a date string and put the comparator there and put it into an array, or ...?

Answer (score 0):

The Collections.Sort method allows you to (optionally) specify your own Comparator. In your case, when you sort the date column you will need to provide your own comparator.

If you are using Java 8 then the code will look something like this:

```
Collections.sort(dataMap.get("Date"), (date1, date2) -> compareDates(date1, date2));
```

The compareDates method would then need to be able to handle nulls and would need to pull apart the date components and return number of days from date1 to date2. You could easily use the java.util.Date object to do that - just convert the dates (possibly using DataFormat) and then compare.